# How to get the value of excel sheet cell using their Field Name

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I want to Extract data from Excel sheet according to header i have specifies in the Sheet.
I am using ClosedXML and getting data using cell Number.Below is my Code.

```
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path1);    
                    //Open uploaded workbook
                    var workBook = new XLWorkbook(fi.FullName);
                    //Get the first sheet of workbook
                    var worksheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

                    var firstRowUsed = worksheet.FirstRowUsed();
                    var categoryRow = firstRowUsed.RowUsed();

               /Get the column names from first row of excel
                Dictionary<int, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<int,string>();
                for (int cell = 1; cell <= categoryRow.CellCount(); cell++)
                {
                    keyValues.Add(cell, categoryRow.Cell(cell).GetString());
                }

                //Get the next row
                categoryRow = categoryRow.RowBelow();
                while (!categoryRow.Cell(coCategoryId).IsEmpty())
                {
                    int count = 1;
                    var pc = new ExpandoObject();
                    while (count <= categoryRow.CellCount())
                    {
                        // let this go through-if the data is bad, it will be rejected by SQL
                        var data = categoryRow.Cell(count).Value;
                        ((IDictionary<string, object>)pc).Add(keyValues[count], data);
                        //((IDictionary<string, object>)pc).Add(keyValues[count], data);
                        fName = categoryRow.Cell(1).Value.ToString();
                        lName = categoryRow.Cell(2).Value.ToString();
                        userGender = categoryRow.Cell(3).Value.ToString();
                        roleTitle = categoryRow.Cell(4).Value.ToString();
                        mobileNumber = categoryRow.Cell(5).Value.ToString();
                        CurrentCity = categoryRow.Cell(6).Value.ToString();
                        country = categoryRow.Cell(7).Value.ToString();
                        birthDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
```

Here is the code now i want to extract data According to field name in excel sheet as Name,lastname,city ....etc.How to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can Do It with OLEDB  to Extract the data from excel file and store it in a Datatable and do whatever you want ,

Here is a function which will return your excel file in DataTable format

```
private System.Data.DataTable call()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        string conStr = "";
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
                break;

            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
                break;
        }
        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, "YES");
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);

        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        connExcel.Open();
        System.Data.DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        connExcel.Close();

        connExcel.Open();


        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT [ColumnName1] , [ColumnName2]  From [report$A10:U16384] where  [ColumnName1] is not null";//any Condition
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();


        return dt;
    }
```